# Flutter: animate layout changes

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to animate page items as they appear? (not with fade effect) like on android, with

```
 android:animateLayoutChanges
```

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRcv8.gif)
[Example 2](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*6BEdt24UippvRjRNgUjZbQ.gif).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [delayed_display](https://pub.dev/packages/delayed_display) pub package.

But if you want to do something custom, for example:

```
AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    height: 50,
    width: isVisible ? 100 : 50,
    color: isVisible ? Colors.yellow : Colors.blue,
);
```